# weka mac installation

Tags: macos, machine-learning, weka

Recently, I bought a new macbook and installed weka. When I double click on the weka icon, it opens and after around 2 seconds, it closes.

I've tried re-installing it several times and also tried different versions. However nothing seems to work.

I've also searched the internet for a solution but can't seem to find one.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are there any messages in the system logs? If you run the program from the command line do you get any error messages printed there?

Comment: hi sarnold, ye these are the error messages:

[JavaAppLauncher Error] CallStaticVoidMethod() threw an exception,,

Exception in thread "main",,

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/eawt/OpenFilesHandler,,

Causedby:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.apple.eawt.OpenFilesHandler

Comment: ok sorted it out, i just needed to update my java version on my mac.

Comment: Please add that as an answer on the question, so that it will be easily available to others in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Sorted it out. I just needed to update my java version on my macbook. Now weka has all the libraries it requires to function properly.